# Why hasn't the UK penalized a Commonwealth Realm for supporting China's National Security Law on Hong Kong?

Tags: united-kingdom, international-relations, commonwealth

According to [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/54380), Antigua and Barbuda (I'll call this AB for short) supported China's National Security Law that the U.K. excoriates. AB is a [Commonwealth Realm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_realm#Current_realms), but I know Commonwealth Realms are sovereign states. But the U.K. can still use its [constitutional and legal roles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchy_of_Antigua_and_Barbuda#Constitutional_role) to influence  AB. UK can theoretically exercise its Crown Prorogative or refuse Royal Assent against AB's intentions, even if "The last bill that was refused assent by the Sovereign was the [Scottish Militia Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Militia_Bill) during [Queen Anne's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne,_Queen_of_Great_Britain) reign in 1708.[[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_assent#cite_note-6)"

1. Thus why hasn't UK reprehended or punished AB? For instance, can't UK disconnect from AB, or have Queen Elizabeth II stop being AB's head of state? Can't UK impose sanctions on AB?
2. How can AB remain a Commonwealth Realm? Because China dislikes the UK, wouldn't China ask AB to leave Commonwealth?

I don't expect AB to reprehend the U.K. for excoriating China's laws, when UK has more capital and power than AB.

Comment: Never give an order you know will not be obeyed.

Comment: If the UK kicked countries out of the Commonwealth for having different foreign relations, there wouldn't be any left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The [Government of Antigua and Barbuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_Antigua_and_Barbuda) advises [the Queen of Antigua and Barbuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_II)'s representative, [the Governor General](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Governor-General_of_Antigua_and_Barbuda), in their role as the head of state of Antigua and Barbuda, to approve or disapprove of legislation.**

The British government doesn't have anything to do with this process on any level as Antigua and Barbuda is an independent country. **The British government cannot advise the Queen to intervene in a different country's internal actions.** It would be similarly illegal for the Prime Minister of the UK to ask the Queen to intervene in Canada or Australia.

As an aside, I *think* the Parliament or Prime Minister of Antigua and Barbuda could, on certain occasions, appeal to the Queen of Antigua and Barbuda to overrule the Governor-General, but this is not very important in this instance.

Meanwhile, the Commonwealth is a voluntary organization and any attempts to use it for hard diplomacy are foolhardy at best. There would be no benefit to trying to evict someone from the Commonwealth for such a diplomatic disagreement while it would cause lots of ill will between the UK and other countries.